# Reduced Docker Image size for Docker file

Tags: dockerfile

I am trying to reduce my Docker image size.

The folder that I am trying to dockerize is `628K` in size. Checked using:

```
du -sh foldername
```

Below is my Docker file:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.5-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Environment variables
ARG access_key
ARG access_secret

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /app
RUN mkdir -p /mountedDir/
RUN mkdir -p ~/.aws/
RUN echo "[default]\naws_access_key_id = $access_key \naws_secret_access_key = $access_secret \n" > ~/.aws/credentials
RUN echo "[profile default]\noutput = json\nregion = us-east-1\n" > ~/.aws/config

ENV LS_COLORS rs=0:di=38;5;27:ln=38;5;51:mh=44;38;5;15:pi=40;38;5;11:so=38;5;13:do=38;5;5:bd=48;5;232;38;5;11:cd=48;5;232;38;5;3:or=48;5;232;38;5;9:mi=05;48;5;232;38;5;15:su=48;5;196;38;5;15:sg=48;5;11;38;5;16:ca=48;5;196;38;5;226:tw=48;5;10;38;5;16:ow=48;5;10;38;5;21:st=48;5;21;38;5;15:ex=38;5;34:*.tar=38;5;9:*.tgz=38;5;9:*.arc=38;5;9:*.arj=38;5;9:*.taz=38;5;9:*.lha=38;5;9:*.lz4=38;5;9:*.lzh=38;5;9:*.lzma=38;5;9:*.tlz=38;5;9:*.txz=38;5;9:*.tzo=38;5;9:*.t7z=38;5;9:*.zip=38;5;9:*.z=38;5;9:*.Z=38;5;9:*.dz=38;5;9:*.gz=38;5;9:*.lrz=38;5;9:*.lz=38;5;9:*.lzo=38;5;9:*.xz=38;5;9:*.bz2=38;5;9:*.bz=38;5;9:*.tbz=38;5;9:*.tbz2=38;5;9:*.tz=38;5;9:*.deb=38;5;9:*.rpm=38;5;9:*.jar=38;5;9:*.war=38;5;9:*.ear=38;5;9:*.sar=38;5;9:*.rar=38;5;9:*.alz=38;5;9:*.ace=38;5;9:*.zoo=38;5;9:*.cpio=38;5;9:*.7z=38;5;9:*.rz=38;5;9:*.cab=38;5;9:*.jpg=38;5;13:*.jpeg=38;5;13:*.gif=38;5;13:*.bmp=38;5;13:*.pbm=38;5;13:*.pgm=38;5;13:*.ppm=38;5;13:*.tga=38;5;13:*.xbm=38;5;13:*.xpm=38;5;13:*.tif=38;5;13:*.tiff=38;5;13:*.png=38;5;13:*.svg=38;5;13:*.svgz=38;5;13:*.mng=38;5;13:*.pcx=38;5;13:*.mov=38;5;13:*.mpg=38;5;13:*.mpeg=38;5;13:*.m2v=38;5;13:*.mkv=38;5;13:*.webm=38;5;13:*.ogm=38;5;13:*.mp4=38;5;13:*.m4v=38;5;13:*.mp4v=38;5;13:*.vob=38;5;13:*.qt=38;5;13:*.nuv=38;5;13:*.wmv=38;5;13:*.asf=38;5;13:*.rm=38;5;13:*.rmvb=38;5;13:*.flc=38;5;13:*.avi=38;5;13:*.fli=38;5;13:*.flv=38;5;13:*.gl=38;5;13:*.dl=38;5;13:*.xcf=38;5;13:*.xwd=38;5;13:*.yuv=38;5;13:*.cgm=38;5;13:*.emf=38;5;13:*.axv=38;5;13:*.anx=38;5;13:*.ogv=38;5;13:*.ogx=38;5;13:*.aac=38;5;45:*.au=38;5;45:*.flac=38;5;45:*.mid=38;5;45:*.midi=38;5;45:*.mka=38;5;45:*.mp3=38;5;45:*.mpc=38;5;45:*.ogg=38;5;45:*.ra=38;5;45:*.wav=38;5;45:*.axa=38;5;45:*.oga=38;5;45:*.spx=38;5;45:*.xspf=38;5;45:

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -qq -y install \
pkg-config \
python3-dev \
python-opencv \
libopencv-dev \
libav-tools  \
libjpeg-dev \
libpng-dev \
libtiff-dev \
libjasper-dev \
python3-pycurl \
python3-tk && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

RUN pip3 freeze

COPY startup.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/startup.sh

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/startup.sh"]
```

The Image that gets created after the build is **>1.8Gb**

The requirements files contain python packages such as opencv-python, Keras, tensorflow-gpu, matplotlib, numpy, scipy, Babel and other small packages.

Is it possible to reduce the image size?

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 2):

The main idea is to group your `RUN` commands into the smallest number possible. Each docker command creates a layer, and the fewer layers you have, the smaller docker image you'll get.

For instance:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.5-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

# Environment variables
ARG access_key
ARG access_secret

RUN mkdir -p /mountedDir/ && \
    mkdir -p ~/.aws/ && \
    echo "[default]\naws_access_key_id = $access_key \naws_secret_access_key = $access_secret \n" > ~/.aws/credentials && \
    echo "[profile default]\noutput = json\nregion = us-east-1\n" > ~/.aws/config

ENV LS_COLORS rs=0:di=38;5;27:ln=38;5;51:mh=44;38;5;15:pi=40;38;5;11:so=38;5;13:do=38;5;5:bd=48;5;232;38;5;11:cd=48;5;232;38;5;3:or=48;5;232;38;5;9:mi=05;48;5;232;38;5;15:su=48;5;196;38;5;15:sg=48;5;11;38;5;16:ca=48;5;196;38;5;226:tw=48;5;10;38;5;16:ow=48;5;10;38;5;21:st=48;5;21;38;5;15:ex=38;5;34:*.tar=38;5;9:*.tgz=38;5;9:*.arc=38;5;9:*.arj=38;5;9:*.taz=38;5;9:*.lha=38;5;9:*.lz4=38;5;9:*.lzh=38;5;9:*.lzma=38;5;9:*.tlz=38;5;9:*.txz=38;5;9:*.tzo=38;5;9:*.t7z=38;5;9:*.zip=38;5;9:*.z=38;5;9:*.Z=38;5;9:*.dz=38;5;9:*.gz=38;5;9:*.lrz=38;5;9:*.lz=38;5;9:*.lzo=38;5;9:*.xz=38;5;9:*.bz2=38;5;9:*.bz=38;5;9:*.tbz=38;5;9:*.tbz2=38;5;9:*.tz=38;5;9:*.deb=38;5;9:*.rpm=38;5;9:*.jar=38;5;9:*.war=38;5;9:*.ear=38;5;9:*.sar=38;5;9:*.rar=38;5;9:*.alz=38;5;9:*.ace=38;5;9:*.zoo=38;5;9:*.cpio=38;5;9:*.7z=38;5;9:*.rz=38;5;9:*.cab=38;5;9:*.jpg=38;5;13:*.jpeg=38;5;13:*.gif=38;5;13:*.bmp=38;5;13:*.pbm=38;5;13:*.pgm=38;5;13:*.ppm=38;5;13:*.tga=38;5;13:*.xbm=38;5;13:*.xpm=38;5;13:*.tif=38;5;13:*.tiff=38;5;13:*.png=38;5;13:*.svg=38;5;13:*.svgz=38;5;13:*.mng=38;5;13:*.pcx=38;5;13:*.mov=38;5;13:*.mpg=38;5;13:*.mpeg=38;5;13:*.m2v=38;5;13:*.mkv=38;5;13:*.webm=38;5;13:*.ogm=38;5;13:*.mp4=38;5;13:*.m4v=38;5;13:*.mp4v=38;5;13:*.vob=38;5;13:*.qt=38;5;13:*.nuv=38;5;13:*.wmv=38;5;13:*.asf=38;5;13:*.rm=38;5;13:*.rmvb=38;5;13:*.flc=38;5;13:*.avi=38;5;13:*.fli=38;5;13:*.flv=38;5;13:*.gl=38;5;13:*.dl=38;5;13:*.xcf=38;5;13:*.xwd=38;5;13:*.yuv=38;5;13:*.cgm=38;5;13:*.emf=38;5;13:*.axv=38;5;13:*.anx=38;5;13:*.ogv=38;5;13:*.ogx=38;5;13:*.aac=38;5;45:*.au=38;5;45:*.flac=38;5;45:*.mid=38;5;45:*.midi=38;5;45:*.mka=38;5;45:*.mp3=38;5;45:*.mpc=38;5;45:*.ogg=38;5;45:*.ra=38;5;45:*.wav=38;5;45:*.axa=38;5;45:*.oga=38;5;45:*.spx=38;5;45:*.xspf=38;5;45:

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -qq -y --no-install-recommends install \
pkg-config \
python3-dev \
python-opencv \
libopencv-dev \
libav-tools  \
libjpeg-dev \
libpng-dev \
libtiff-dev \
libjasper-dev \
python3-pycurl \
python3-tk && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt && pip3 freeze

COPY startup.sh /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/startup.sh

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/startup.sh"]
```

I suggest you have a `bin` directory with a bash script, having all the complex commands so that you nearly have only one `RUN` command and maybe even replace the `ENV` with an `export` command.

```
RUN ./bin/docker-install.sh
```

**EDIT:** Try the below script alternative version

*./bin/docker-install.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

# Print all executed commands to the terminal
set -x

# Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status
set -e

apt-get update && apt-get install -q -y --no-install-recommends \
    pkg-config \
    python3-dev \
    python-opencv \
    libopencv-dev \
    libav-tools  \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libtiff-dev \
    libjasper-dev \
    python3-pycurl \
    python3-tk

rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

mkdir -p /mountedDir/
mkdir -p ~/.aws/

echo "[default]\naws_access_key_id = $access_key \naws_secret_access_key = $access_secret \n" > ~/.aws/credentials
echo "[profile default]\noutput = json\nregion = us-east-1\n" > ~/.aws/config

LS_COLORS='rs=0:di=38;5;27:ln=38;5;51:mh=44;38;5;15:pi=40;38;5;11:so=38;5;13:do=38;5;5:bd=48;5;232;38;5;11:cd=48;5;232;38;5;3:or=48;5;232;38;5;9:mi=05;48;5;232;38;5;15:su=48;5;196;38;5;15:sg=48;5;11;38;5;16:ca=48;5;196;38;5;226:tw=48;5;10;38;5;16:ow=48;5;10;38;5;21:st=48;5;21;38;5;15:ex=38;5;34:*.tar=38;5;9:*.tgz=38;5;9:*.arc=38;5;9:*.arj=38;5;9:*.taz=38;5;9:*.lha=38;5;9:*.lz4=38;5;9:*.lzh=38;5;9:*.lzma=38;5;9:*.tlz=38;5;9:*.txz=38;5;9:*.tzo=38;5;9:*.t7z=38;5;9:*.zip=38;5;9:*.z=38;5;9:*.Z=38;5;9:*.dz=38;5;9:*.gz=38;5;9:*.lrz=38;5;9:*.lz=38;5;9:*.lzo=38;5;9:*.xz=38;5;9:*.bz2=38;5;9:*.bz=38;5;9:*.tbz=38;5;9:*.tbz2=38;5;9:*.tz=38;5;9:*.deb=38;5;9:*.rpm=38;5;9:*.jar=38;5;9:*.war=38;5;9:*.ear=38;5;9:*.sar=38;5;9:*.rar=38;5;9:*.alz=38;5;9:*.ace=38;5;9:*.zoo=38;5;9:*.cpio=38;5;9:*.7z=38;5;9:*.rz=38;5;9:*.cab=38;5;9:*.jpg=38;5;13:*.jpeg=38;5;13:*.gif=38;5;13:*.bmp=38;5;13:*.pbm=38;5;13:*.pgm=38;5;13:*.ppm=38;5;13:*.tga=38;5;13:*.xbm=38;5;13:*.xpm=38;5;13:*.tif=38;5;13:*.tiff=38;5;13:*.png=38;5;13:*.svg=38;5;13:*.svgz=38;5;13:*.mng=38;5;13:*.pcx=38;5;13:*.mov=38;5;13:*.mpg=38;5;13:*.mpeg=38;5;13:*.m2v=38;5;13:*.mkv=38;5;13:*.webm=38;5;13:*.ogm=38;5;13:*.mp4=38;5;13:*.m4v=38;5;13:*.mp4v=38;5;13:*.vob=38;5;13:*.qt=38;5;13:*.nuv=38;5;13:*.wmv=38;5;13:*.asf=38;5;13:*.rm=38;5;13:*.rmvb=38;5;13:*.flc=38;5;13:*.avi=38;5;13:*.fli=38;5;13:*.flv=38;5;13:*.gl=38;5;13:*.dl=38;5;13:*.xcf=38;5;13:*.xwd=38;5;13:*.yuv=38;5;13:*.cgm=38;5;13:*.emf=38;5;13:*.axv=38;5;13:*.anx=38;5;13:*.ogv=38;5;13:*.ogx=38;5;13:*.aac=38;5;45:*.au=38;5;45:*.flac=38;5;45:*.mid=38;5;45:*.midi=38;5;45:*.mka=38;5;45:*.mp3=38;5;45:*.mpc=38;5;45:*.ogg=38;5;45:*.ra=38;5;45:*.wav=38;5;45:*.axa=38;5;45:*.oga=38;5;45:*.spx=38;5;45:*.xspf=38;5;45:';
export LS_COLORS

pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
pip3 freeze
```

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM python:3.5-slim

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

ARG access_key
ARG access_secret

RUN ./bin/docker-install.sh

COPY startup.sh /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/startup.sh

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/startup.sh"]
```

Comment: I tried this and the number of layers reduces as you pointed out but the size of the layer for the `RUN` command increases. So overall the image size remains the same.

Comment: Try adding `--no-install-recommends` to your `apt-get install` like I edited in my answer. By default, it installs recommended but not suggested packages, this way only the main dependencies are installed. I gained 200MB in doing this with your example